# How to retrieve id of persisted object in Service layer in the same method where is persisted with Hibernate + JPA in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Learner object that  sign-up to one or multiple Courses. Learner table has a relation one-to-many with LearnerSubmittedToCourse. In my repository, I save the Learner object in PostgreSql, but after, when I try to find the id of Lerner as to send in LearnerSubmittedToCourse table, I cannot access it (or it is not already perssited).

learner1 object should contain the current learner id but it dosent.

OBS. The Learner id is auto-generated in db !! Learner obj doesent contain the id.

My Service:

```
@Override
public LearnerDto createLearner(LearnerDto learnerDto) {
    Optional<Domain> domain = domainRepository.findById(learnerDto.getDomain().getId());
    Optional<WorkExperience> workExperience = workExperienceRepository.findById(learnerDto.getDomain().getId());
    domain.ifPresent(d -> {
        workExperience.ifPresent(w -> {
            Learner learner = new Learner()
                    .setFirstName(learnerDto.getFirstName())
                    .setLastName(learnerDto.getLastName())
                    .setMobileNo(learnerDto.getMobileNo())
                    .setEmail(learnerDto.getEmail())
                    .setLastJob(learnerDto.getLastJob())
                    .setJob(learnerDto.getJob())
                    .setLearnerDateCreated(learnerDto.getLearnerDateCreated())
                    .setLearnerDetails(learnerDto.getLearnerDetails())
                    .setWhereYouFindUs(learnerDto.getWhereYouFindUs())
                    .setIsCareer(learnerDto.getIsCareer())
                    .setIsBusiness(learnerDto.getIsBusiness())
                    .setObservation(learnerDto.getObservation())
                    .setIsGDPRAccepted(learnerDto.getIsGDPRAccepted())
                    .setScheduledCoursesList(foundScheduledCoursesList)
                    .setDomain(d)
                    .setWorkExperience(w);
            learnerRepository.save(learner);
            Learner learner1 = learnerRepository.findById(learnerDto.getId());

            for (ScheduledCourses course : learnerDto.getScheduledCoursesList()
            ) {
                Optional<ScheduledCourses> foundCourse = scheduledCoursesRepository.findById(course.getId());
                foundCourse.ifPresent(c -> {
                    learnerSubmittedToCourseService.registerLearnerToScheduledCourse(learner1, course);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    return learnerDto;
}

public void registerLearnerToScheduledCourse(Learner learner, ScheduledCourses scheduledCourses) {
Optional<Learner> foundLearner = learnerRepository.findById(learner.getId());
Optional<ScheduledCourses> foundScheduledCourse = scheduledCoursesRepository.findById(scheduledCourses.getId());
foundLearner.ifPresent(l -> {
    foundScheduledCourse.ifPresent(c -> {
        LearnerSubmittedToCourse learnerSubmittedToCourse = new LearnerSubmittedToCourse()
                .setLearner(l)
                .setScheduledCourses(c);
        learnersSubmittedToCourseRepository.save(learnerSubmittedToCourse);
    });
});
```

How can I get my Learner id as to use it in LearnerSubmittedToCourse object?

Comment: You can directly get the saved entity from .save method so you don’t need to find it again. Further where do you set the ID you are searching for. Couldn’t find it in your mapping

Comment: could you just replace `Learner learner1 = learnerRepository.findById(learnerDto.getId());` with `Learner learner1 = learner;` ?

Comment: @tremendous7 because the id is auto-generated with hibernate. I dont;t have acces to it

Comment: You should use less lambdas, break the code down and debug it properly in the IDE. Find out what's happening at each step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`learnerRepository.save(learner);` is returning the instance you are looking for.

`learner = learnerRepository.save(learner);` Now the id should be set correctly on `learner`.

Comment: Technically although it's bad code, not assigning the result should still update the object being saved in these scenarios.. so potentially this won't solve the issue

Comment: If the id is not set on save maybe there is a problem with the hibernate configuration

Comment: no, it's not. it works for others objects

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that in the service code you posted as part of your question, you create and save a new `Learner` from the info in the DTO. However, the ID which is generated during the `save` is set on the entity and not on the DTO, so the following call cannot work:

```
Learner learner1 = learnerRepository.findById(
          learnerDto.getId() // <-- the DTO does not know about the generated ID
                    );
```